# What result in too many connections in mysql

Tags: php, mysql

The value of `max_connections` in my database is 312 and I just run 200 php threads which result in too many connections error.

And I cut off 100 threads, but still with almost 200 database connections used.

I wonder why so many connection are used and how can I do to solve the problem without increasing the value `max_connections`

```
$pdo = get_service("user"); // get a new pdo object
$stmt = $pdo->prepare("...");
$stmt->execute(...);
return $stmt->fetch(\PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
```

Comment: share you code of `connection` and `close` ?

Comment: Well, after every change, you need to restart server.

Comment: Sounds like you're not closing your connections when you're done with them.

Comment: @Rishi Raut Whenever a request arrives, new a `PDO` object for database operation without calling close method

Comment: share that PDO connection code ? May be you are not closing connection

Comment: @DusteD I think the connection will be recycle automatically

Comment: @Rishi Raut I have update my PDO connection code

Comment: Finally after 1hrs , Thanks bro :) and what does `get_service` ?

Comment: @Rishi Raut Just return a new PDO like this: `return new \PDO(...);`

Comment: why are not creating like `$pdo = new PDO("mysql:host=$host;dbname=$dbname",$user,$pass);` directly ?

Comment: @Rishi Raut This is some difference between `new PDO` with `new \PDO`

Answer (score 0):

One simple solution is: **restart your mysql server**

Hope this will resolve your problem without increasing value of max_connections